# How do i customize the response gotten from python "djoser" package when creating a user

Tags: django-rest-framework, djoser

I had to override the serializer to make some changes, but after successful creation/registration, I want to customize the output

##### Serializer override

```
class RegisterSerializer(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer):
first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

class Meta(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer.Meta):
    model = get_user_model()
    # add extra fields to the "djoser" default fields
    fields = UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer.Meta.fields + ("first_name", "last_name")
```

##### output

```
{
"email": "test14@user.com",
"id": 17,
"first_name": "reni",
"last_name": "brake"
```

}

##### desired output

```
{
"data": {
    "email": "test14@user.com",
    "id": 17,
    "first_name": "reni",
    "last_name": "brake"
},
"success": True
```

}